# Unit testing the AngularJS $window service

Tags: angularjs

I would like to unit test the following AngularJs service:

```
.factory('httpResponseInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', '$window', 'CONTEXT_PATH', function($q, $location, $window, contextPath){
     return {
         response : function (response) {
             //Will only be called for HTTP up to 300
             return response;
         },
         responseError: function (rejection) {
             if(rejection.status === 405 || rejection.status === 401) {
                 $window.location.href = contextPath + '/signin';
             }
             return $q.reject(rejection);
         }
     };
}]);
```

I have tried with the following suite:

```
describe('Controllers', function () {
    var $scope, ctrl;
    beforeEach(module('curriculumModule'));
    beforeEach(module('curriculumControllerModule'));
    beforeEach(module('curriculumServiceModule'));
    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
       $provide.constant('CONTEXT_PATH', 'bignibou'); // override contextPath here
    }));
    describe('CreateCurriculumCtrl', function () {
        var mockBackend, location, _window;
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, $location, $window) {
            mockBackend = $httpBackend;
            location = $location;
            _window = $window;
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('CreateCurriculumCtrl', {
                $scope: $scope
            });
        }));

        it('should redirect to /signin if 401 or 405', function () {
            mockBackend.whenGET('bignibou/utils/findLanguagesByLanguageStartingWith.json?language=fran').respond([{"description":"Français","id":46,"version":0}]);
            mockBackend.whenPOST('bignibou/curriculum/new').respond(function(method, url, data, headers){
                return [401];
            });
            $scope.saveCurriculum();
            mockBackend.flush();
            expect(_window.location.href).toEqual("/bignibou/signin");
        });


    });
});
```

However, it fails with the following error message:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Linux) Controllers CreateCurriculumCtrl should redirect to /signin if 401 or 405 FAILED
    Expected 'http://localhost:9876/context.html' to equal '/bignibou/signin'.
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Linux) ERROR
    Some of your tests did a full page reload!
```

I am not sure what is going wrong and why. Can anyone please help?

I just want to ensure the  `$window.location.href` is equal to **`'/bignibou/signin'`**.

**edit 1**:

I managed to get it to work as follows (thanks to "dskh"):

```
 beforeEach(module('config', function($provide){
      $provide.value('$window', {location:{href:'dummy'}});
 }));
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can inject stub dependencies when you load in your module:

```
angular.mock.module('curriculumModule', function($provide){
            $provide.value('$window', {location:{href:'dummy'}});
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. What I am supposed to use as the value for `$window` instead of `{}`?

Comment: whatever you want :).  You probably just want to check that $window.location is not undefined so that you can check it later on when your test sets it to a value

Comment: I am using this method as well, but it breaks my tests that are referencing $location. How do you mock $window and get $location to reference it?

Comment: If you stub $location too, it will no longer reference $window.

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work for me I had to make a minor adjustment. It would error out and say:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$window.navigator.userAgent')`

So I added the `navigator.userAgent` object to get it to work for me.

```
$provide.value('$window', {
  location:{
    href:'dummy'
  },
  navigator:{
    userAgent:{}
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, and went a step further in my solution. I didn't just want a mock, I wanted to replace `$window.location.href` with a Jasmine spy for the better ability to track changes made to it. So, I learned from [apsiller's example for spying on getters/setters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33169197/3123195) and after creating my mock, I was able to spy on the property I wanted.

First, here's a suite that shows how I mocked `$window`, with a test to demonstrate that the spy works as expected:

```
describe("The Thing", function() {
    var $window;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module("app", function ($provide) {
            $provide.value("$window", {
                //this creates a copy that we can edit later
                location: angular.extend({}, window.location)
            });
        });

        inject(function (_$window_) {
            $window = _$window_;
        });
    });

    it("should track calls to $window.location.href", function() {
        var hrefSpy = spyOnProperty($window.location, 'href', 'set');

        console.log($window.location.href);
        $window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
        console.log($window.location.href);

        expect(hrefSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(hrefSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("https://www.google.com/");
    });
});
```

As you can see above, the spy is generated by calling the below function: (it works for both `get` and `set`)

```
function spyOnProperty(obj, propertyName, accessType) {
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, propertyName);

    if (desc.hasOwnProperty("value")) {
        //property is a value, not a getter/setter - convert it
        var value = desc.value;

        desc = {
            get: function() { return value; },
            set: function(input) { value = input; }
        }
    }

    var spy = jasmine.createSpy(propertyName, desc[accessType]).and.callThrough();

    desc[accessType] = spy;
    Object.defineProperty(obj, propertyName, desc);

    return spy;
}
```

Lastly, [here's a fiddle demonstrating this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/3stwu09v/). I've tested this against Angular 1.4, and Jasmine 2.3 and 2.4.

Comment: As of Jasmine 2.6 (maybe earlier, not sure) `spyOnProperty` has been merged into core and doesn't need to be implemented by the user: https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#spyOnProperty