# unit testing angular issue with window location assign

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocking, mocha.js, angular-mock

In my ctrl, I have this code to navigate to a page after the function has completed its work.

```
 $scope.myFunction = function(){
     //other code
     window.location.assign(url);
 }
```

My test code looks like this.

```
   describe('TEST', function () {
      var window;

      beforeEach(module(function($provide) {  
       //dummy window    
       window = {            
           location:{href:function(){return 'dummy'},assign:function()
            {return 'dummy1'}}   
        };        

         // We register our new $window instead of the old    
            $provide.constant('$window',window);        
         }));

       it("should test",function(){
            $scope.myfunction();
       });
});

  The error that I get is ..Some of your tests did a full page reload! and the test fails.
```

I've followed the issue documented here ([Unit testing the AngularJS $window service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645614/unit-testing-the-angularjs-window-service)), but the same approach doesn't work for me. any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function needs $window injected, not window

```
$scope.myFunction = function($window){
     //other code
     $window.location.assign(url);
 }
```

As written, you are bypassing the mocked $window service and acting on the actual native window object.